# How to take input from console at runtime in e2e tests

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm running some e2e specs and trying to accept user input value manually at run-time from the console. The user input value needs to be then submitted to a text field. Is there a way to hold e2e test while the user inputs a value from console and then the test resume & that value can be used and supplied to any target object (a text box etc.). Is there a way to do so?

I'm using Protractor with Jasmine.

Thanks